# stored procedure php pdo with mariadb - doing something wrong

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Full disclaimer I have never messed around with stored procedures before, but am pretty competent with regular queries.  I am getting no results from this stored procedure test I have created and I know there are results as I can get them from a 'normal' query.  What am I doing wrong with this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_snet(
    IN one VARCHAR(255),
    IN two VARCHAR(255)
)

BEGIN
    SELECT
        IFNULL( (SELECT cats FROM results081219 WHERE url = @one LIMIT 1), '') AS cats1,
        IFNULL( (SELECT cats FROM results081219 WHERE url = @two LIMIT 1), '') AS cats2;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

php:

```
$parsed1 = 'google.com';
$parsed2 = 'gmail.com';

//stored procedure way
$stmt = $dbnet->prepare("
    CALL get_snet(:parsed1, :parsed2);  
");

$binding = array(
    'parsed1' => $parsed1,
    'parsed2' => $parsed2
);
$stmt->execute($binding);

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($results);
echo "</pre>";
```

results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cats1] => 
            [cats2] => 
        )

)
```

Also, is it required to define VARCHAR(xxx) for strings in the stored procedure?  In my normal query, since this string is provided by php there is no defined length and I would like to keep it the same.

Answer (score 1):

`@one` is for a mysql session variable. which has its uses.

What you need to do is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_snet(
    IN one VARCHAR(255),
    IN two VARCHAR(255)
)

BEGIN
    SELECT
        IFNULL( (SELECT cats FROM results081219 WHERE url = one LIMIT 1), '') AS cats1,
        IFNULL( (SELECT cats FROM results081219 WHERE url = two LIMIT 1), '') AS cats2;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: That did the trick and it is working, but when I perform a query after this one I get 'Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.' now.

Comment: If you do not fetch all of the data in a result set before issuing your next call to PDO::query(), your call may fail. Call PDOStatement::closeCursor() to release the database resources associated with the PDOStatement object before issuing your next call to PDO::query().  so use $stmt->closeCursor(); before the next pdo statement